# Visibility Not working with Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin

Hi the Given below is my Code, where my button should become INVISIBLE but the INVISIBLE is not working

```
fun onPlay(view: View){
         var play = findViewById(R.id.play) as Button
         play.isClickable=false
         play.visibility=view.INVISIBLE
}
```

Comment: There is no issue with this code. Are you sure you have the right ID for the button? Are you sure this code is being called?

Comment: Code is being called but the INVISIBLE part is becoming red while typing itself.

Comment: Error is Unresolved reference : INVISIBLE

Comment: Indeed, the problem caught by the submitted answer below is right, that should be `View.INVISIBLE` or simply `INVISIBLE` instead.

Comment: @zsmb13 So, if my answer is right, why don't you vote up?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

You have a mistake in your code, visibility constant should be set from Class variable, not from argument variable. Change view.INVISIBLE by View.INVISIBLE

```
fun onPlay(view: View){
     var play = findViewById(R.id.play) as Button
     play.isClickable=false
     play.visibility= View.INVISIBLE // v letter should be capital
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the Input

Comment: (view!!.findViewById(R.id.play) as Button).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE)

Answer (score 5):

use `play.visibility=View.VISIBLE` to visible and `play.visibility=View.GONE` to invisible or to hide